# Вывести количество записей в таблице News для каждой записи в таблице Categories

Tags: django, orm

Вывести количество записей в таблице News для каждой записи в таблице Categories. Отсортировать записи по имени категории в порядке возрастания

Связь M2M

Привет, есть сложности с ОРМ

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def publish(self):
        self.is_published = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Запрос на posgresql написать смог, а как перенести его на django ORM пока не знаю.

```
SELECT ct.name, count(n.category_id) FROM category ct 
LEFT JOIN news n ON ct.id=n.category_id 
GROUP BY ct.name, category_id 
ORDER BY category_id DESC
```

Не понимаю как работать с агрегатными функциями и забирать нужные поля из выборки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется сортировка по имени категории в порядке возрастания запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT "category"."name" AS "name", COUNT("news"."id") AS "cnt"
FROM "news"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "news_category" ON ("news"."id" = "news_category"."news_id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "category" ON ("news_category"."category_id" = "category"."id")
GROUP BY "category"."name"
ORDER BY "category"."name" ASC;
```

ORM:

```
queryset = (
    News
    .objects
    .values('category__name')
    .annotate(name=F('category__name'))
    .annotate(cnt=Count('id'))
    .order_by('category__name')
    .values('name', 'cnt')
)
```